# Are Excel grid lines part of the cell or extra space?

Tags: .net, grid

I'm creating a grid usercontrol, and I want to show grid lines.

As a reference, I took a look at Excel.
Between Excel cells there are thin grid lines.
Now when it comes to calculating the grid lines in my usercontrol, I wonder if these grid lines should be drawn as a part of a cell so that they just draw over the cells, or if they should be drawn between cells.

I'm asking about Excel specifically because in Excel, you can join / combine cells, so I'm even more confused if grid lines are actually part of a cell (and drawn over it) or some extra space.

Does anybody have any advice or knows how it's done in Excel?
I didn't see a way to investigate how Excel does this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid lines in Excel are drawn simply over the cells, there are no extra calculations done.

You can confirm this by making the grid lines invisible.
As you can see, nothing changes in regards to the cell width / height.